# Converter caminho (String) para objeto

Tags: javascript, funções, conversão-de-tipo

Preciso de uma função que converta:

`"/home/username/Documentos/app.txt"`

para um objeto:

```
{
  "home": {
    "username":{
    "Documentos":
     "app.txt":{}
    }
  }
}
```

`

Estava pensando em quebrar a string pelas "/", mas não achei uma maneira de colocar os índices um dentro do outro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usa um split para "partir" essa String e depois um loop que vai criando um objeto.

Podia ser assim:

```js
var string = "/home/username/Documentos/app.txt";
var props = string.split('/').filter(Boolean); // para limpar e tirar o primeiro elemento
var prop; // a propriedade que vamos iterar
var obj = {}; // o objeto final
var temp = obj; // o ponteiro que vamos mudando para criar sub-objetos
while (prop = props.shift()) {
  temp[prop] = {};
  temp = temp[prop];
}
console.log(obj);
```

Uma versão mais compacta com ES2015 poderia ser:

```js
function objectify(str) {
  const obj = {}, props = str.split('/').filter(Boolean)
  let prop, temp = obj;
  while (prop = props.shift()) temp = temp[prop] = {};
  return obj;
}
console.log(objectify("/home/username/Documentos/app.txt"));
```

Comment: Esta realmente era a minha lógica, só não estava conseguindo entender a minha própria lógica. Gostei bastante da versão com ES6 muito obrigado!